# How to access the most recent added node to Tree View in a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, treeview, nodes

If I add a new node programmatically how do I edit its properties? Say I wanted to change the text right after for example. I can do this normally by using:

```
treeView1.Nodes[indexOfNode].text = "newText";
```

but it seems like there's no way to edit the nodes properties without knowing the name of it. It's sort of an awkward situation. Is there no such thing as a way to go:

```
treeView1.Nodes.lastNodeAdded?
```

Comment: You can access the treeView1.LastNode but that's not necessarily the most recently added Node

Comment: The Add is a function, so `TreeNode tn = tv.Nodes.Add("New Node");`

Comment: @LarsTech yeah that works but not programattically. I can't have multiple nodes with the same name right? I'm having the user click a button to add a node each time.

Comment: Why don't you try it first.  :-)

Comment: ! it works ! but why? I thought it's impossible to have two variables of the same name??

Comment: I think you are confusing a variable name and a node key.  While keys should be unique, the TreeView doesn't impose any rule against duplicates.  If you are expecting unique keys for your nodes, it's up to you to make sure that happens.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks a lot, I have 1 last qustion about nodes but can't post for 90 minutes. Can I ask you here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about?

```
    TreeNode n = treeView1.Nodes.Add("test");
    n.Text = "test 2";
```

Comment: see my comment @LarsTech in the question. 3rd one down. Thanks for the idea though